# Visual Studio Code Extension Testing - disable File Watcher warnings and errors in the terminal test execution output

Tags: vscode-extensions

if i execute my tests with `vscode-test` which uses `mocha` then i see multiple File Watcher warnings and errors. This is annoying and i am asking if there is a possibility to disable or hide those messages.

```bash
dirk.schiller@master % npm test

> testplan-manager@0.0.8 pretest
> rm -rf ./out; npm run compile


> testplan-manager@0.0.8 compile
> tsc -p ./


> testplan-manager@0.0.8 test
> vscode-test

Found existing install in /Volumes/K2TB/Work/Coding/VSCode/Testplan Manager/master/.vscode-test/vscode-darwin-arm64-1.86.0. Skipping download
2024-02-07 10:22:27.996 Electron[93708:10552672] WARNING: Secure coding is not enabled for restorable state! Enable secure coding by implementing NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState: and returning YES.
[main 2024-02-07T09:22:28.109Z] update#setState disabled
[main 2024-02-07T09:22:28.109Z] update#ctor - updates are disabled by the environment
[main 2024-02-07T09:22:28.196Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] Refusing to watch /Volumes/K2TB/Work/Coding/VSCode/Testplan Manager/master/.vscode-test/user-data/User for changes using fs.watch() for possibly being a network share where watching is unreliable and unstable.
[main 2024-02-07T09:22:28.196Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] Refusing to watch /Volumes/K2TB/Work/Coding/VSCode/Testplan Manager/master/.vscode-test/user-data/User/settings.json for changes using fs.watch() for possibly being a network share where watching is unreliable and unstable.
2024-02-07 10:22:28.424 Code Helper (Renderer)[93713:10552762] CoreText note: Client requested name ".NewYork-Regular", it will get TimesNewRomanPSMT rather than the intended font. All system UI font access should be through proper APIs such as CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage() or +[NSFont systemFontOfSize:].
2024-02-07 10:22:28.424 Code Helper (Renderer)[93713:10552762] CoreText note: Set a breakpoint on CTFontLogSystemFontNameRequest to debug.
Started local extension host with pid 93730.
Loading development extension at /Volumes/K2TB/Work/Coding/VSCode/Testplan Manager/master
[main 2024-02-07T09:22:28.757Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] Refusing to watch /Volumes/K2TB/Work/Coding/VSCode/Testplan Manager/master/.vscode-test/user-data/User for changes using fs.watch() for possibly being a network share where watching is unreliable and unstable.
[main 2024-02-07T09:22:28.757Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] Refusing to watch /Volumes/K2TB/Work/Coding/VSCode/Testplan Manager/master/.vscode-test/user-data/User/settings.json for changes using fs.watch() for possibly being a network share where watching is unreliable and unstable.
[File Watcher (node.js)] Refusing to watch /Volumes/K2TB/Work/Coding/VSCode/Testplan Manager/master/.vscode-test/user-data/User for changes using fs.watch() for possibly being a network share where watching is unreliable and unstable.
[File Watcher (node.js)] Refusing to watch /Volumes/K2TB/Work/Coding/VSCode/Testplan Manager/master/.vscode-test/user-data/User/settings.json for changes using fs.watch() for possibly being a network share where watching is unreliable and unstable.
[File Watcher (node.js)] Refusing to watch /Volumes/K2TB/Work/Coding/VSCode/Testplan Manager/master/.vscode-test/user-data/User/snippets for changes using fs.watch() for possibly being a network share where watching is unreliable and unstable.
[File Watcher (node.js)] Refusing to watch /Volumes/K2TB/Work/Coding/VSCode/Testplan Manager/master/.vscode-test/vscode-darwin-arm64-1.86.0/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/theme-abyss/themes/abyss-color-theme.json for changes using fs.watch() for possibly being a network share where watching is unreliable and unstable.
[File Watcher (node.js)] Refusing to watch /Volumes/K2TB/Work/Coding/VSCode/Testplan Manager/master/.vscode-test/vscode-darwin-arm64-1.86.0/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/theme-defaults/fileicons/vs_minimal-icon-theme.json for changes using fs.watch() for possibly being a network share where watching is unreliable and unstable.
[main 2024-02-07T09:22:28.845Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] Refusing to watch /Volumes/K2TB/Work/Coding/VSCode/Testplan Manager/master/.vscode-test/extensions for changes using fs.watch() for possibly being a network share where watching is unreliable and unstable.
[main 2024-02-07T09:22:28.846Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] Refusing to watch /Volumes/K2TB/Work/Coding/VSCode/Testplan Manager/master/.vscode-test/extensions/extensions.json for changes using fs.watch() for possibly being a network share where watching is unreliable and unstable.

  Extension Test Suite
    ✔ Command `testplanManager.general.enableCodeLens` should enable Code Lens (142ms)
    ✔ Command `testplanManager.general.disableCodeLens` should disable Code Lens (103ms)
    ✔ CodeLenses are created for Testplan File and the correct ammount of CodeLenses are created (224ms)
[File Watcher (node.js)] Refusing to watch /Volumes/K2TB/Work/Coding/VSCode/Testplan Manager/master/out/testFiles/testTestplan.tp for changes using fs.watch() for possibly being a network share where watching is unreliable and unstable.
    ✔ Testplan Explorer shows correct tree (132ms)
  4 passing (657ms)
[main 2024-02-07T09:22:29.862Z] Extension host with pid 93730 exited with code: 0, signal: unknown.
Exit code:   0
Done

dirk.schiller@master %
```

I am using code that overwrites the configuration for the VSCode testing instance:

###### src/test/suite/index.ts

```js
import * as path from 'path';
import * as Mocha from 'mocha';
import * as glob from 'glob';
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

// Function to change a complex setting
async function changeComplexSetting(key: string, value: any): Promise<void> {
    const configuration = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration();
    await configuration.update(key, value, vscode.ConfigurationTarget.Global); // Update the setting globally
}

export function run(): Promise<void> {
    
    // Change the value of 'files.watcherExclude'
    const newValue = {
        "**/.git/objects/**": true,
        "**/.git/subtree-cache/**": true,
        "**/node_modules/*/**": true,
        "**/.vscode-test/user-data/**": true,
        "**/out/**": true,
        "**" : true
    };

    changeComplexSetting('files.watcherExclude', newValue).then(() => {
        console.debug('Setting updated successfully');
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error('Error updating setting:', error);
    });

    changeComplexSetting('workbench.colorTheme', 'Default Dark Modern').then(() => {
        console.debug('Setting updated successfully');
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error('Error updating setting:', error);
    });

    // Create the mocha test
    const mocha = new Mocha({
        ui: 'tdd'
    });

    const testsRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');

    return new Promise((c, e) => {
        glob('**/**.test.js', { cwd: testsRoot }, (err, files) => {
            if (err) {
                return e(err);
            }

            // Add files to the test suite
            files.forEach(f => mocha.addFile(path.resolve(testsRoot, f)));

            try {
                // Run the mocha test
                mocha.run(failures => {
                    if (failures > 0) {
                        e(new Error(`${failures} tests failed.`));
                    } else {
                        c();
                    }
                });
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
                e(err);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

And except changing the theme, the file watcher settings seem not to work.

Any help and idea is appreciated.